# Proving that if $x,y \in \mathbb{F}$, then there exists a unique $a \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $xa=y$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, and $x,y \in \mathbb{F}$ where $x\neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$. I am trying to show there exists a unique $a \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $x\cdot a=y$. My proof is as follows:

Suppose $a$ and $a^*$ both satisfy $x\cdot a = y$ and $x \cdot a^* = y$, respectively. Then,

$$
x\cdot a = y = x \cdot a^* \implies x\cdot a = x \cdot a^*
$$

Then, taking inverse of $x$ of both sides, yields:

$$
a = a^*
$$

Is this proof correct? Thanks!

Comment: You mean multiplying by the inverse of $x$. But you still haven't shown existence.

Comment: You've proven if such an a exists it's unique correctly.  But you haven't shown any such a exists in the first place.

Comment: Fields are axiomatically equipped with inverses. OP doesn't need to prove anything, but rather realize this is almost a restatement of the field axioms.

Comment: The op must certainly does need to prove something. By axiomatic definition for every x there is an x' so that xx' = identity but nothing is given about for x and y there is an a so ax=y. But that is a very *basic* proposition following directly from the axiom and nothing else. But it is a proposition, not an axiom.  It's *almost* a restatement but not quite.  It could serve as an alternative definition, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, but only for uniqueness. For the existence, since $x^{-1}y\in \mathbb{F}$, there exists $a\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $x^{-1}y=a$. Therefore $y=xa$.